# Add white breaking line after text in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, textarea

I want to have a breaking line or two breaking lines after the text in a textarea without the user hitting "Enter" for a new line so that empty line will show up in printed page

```html
<html >
<head>

<!-- script print button -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function printTextArea() {
 
        childWindow = window.open('','childWindow','location=yes, menubar=yes, toolbar=yes');
        childWindow.document.open();
        childWindow.document.write('<html><head></head><body dir="rtl">');
        childWindow.document.write(document.getElementById('targetTextArea').value.replace(/\n/gi,'<br/>'));
        childWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        childWindow.print();
        childWindow.document.close();
        childWindow.close();
      }
    </script>
<style type="text/css">

textarea {
direction: rtl; 
 background-color: white;
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 border: 1px solid #00acee;
 resize: none;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <TEXTAREA name="thetext" rows="20" cols="80"id="targetTextArea" placeholder="قم بنسخ و لصق الطلب لملأه و التعديل عليه و طباعته بالزر أسفله ......">
</TEXTAREA>
   </p>
   <!-- print button -->
  <center> <input type="button" onclick="printTextArea()" value="طباعة"/></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. If padding doesn't look good try adding a margin.

```
@media print {
   textarea {padding-bottom:2cm;}
}
```

Comment: close answer without "@media print" just css   textarea {padding-bottom:2cm;} and you will have 2cm empty white space in the buttom of the textarea even though the problem that textarea get expanded by 2cm